# Parallel Command Pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop

I wanted to know of how to make my use of the command pattern thread-safe while maintaining performance. I have a simulation where I perform upwards of *tens of billions* of iterations; performance is critical.

In this simulation, I have a bunch of `Moves` that perform commands on objects in my simulation. The base class looks like this:

```
class Move
    {
        public:
            virtual ~Move(){}

            // Perform a move.
            virtual void Perform(Object& obj) = 0;

            // Undo a move.
            virtual void Undo() = 0;
    };
```

The reason I have the object passed in on `Perform` rather than the constructor, as is typical with the Command pattern, is that I cannot afford to instantiate a new `Move` object every iteration. Rather, a concrete implementation of `Move` would simply take `Object`, maintain a pointer to it and it's previous state for when it's needed. Here's an example of a concrete implementation:

```
class ConcreteMove : public Move
    {
        std::string _ns;
        std::string _prev;
        Object* _obj;
        ConcreteMove(std::string newstring): _ns(newstring) {}            


        virtual void Perform(Object& obj) override
        {
            _obj= &obj;
            _prev = obj.GetIdentifier();
            obj.SetIdentifier(_ns);
        }

        virtual void Undo()
        {
            _obj->SetIdentifier(_prev);
        }
    };
```

Unfortunately, what this has cost me is thread-safety. I want to parallelize my loop, where multiple iterators perform moves on a bunch of objects simultaneously. But obviously one instance of `ConcreteMove` cannot be reused because of how I implemented it.

I considered having `Perform` return a `State` object which can be passed into `Undo`, that way making the implementation thread-safe, since it is independent of the `ConcereteMove` state. However, the creation and destruction of such an object on each iteration is too costly.

Furthermore, the simulation has a vector of `Moves` because multiple moves can be performed every iteration stored in a `MoveManager` class which contains a vector of `Move` object pointers instantiated by the client. I set it up this way because the constructors of each particular Concrete moves take parameters (see above example).

I considered writing a copy operator for `Move` and `MoveManager` such that it can be duplicated amongst the threads, but I don't believe that is a proper answer because then the ownership of the `Move` objects falls on `MoveManager` rather than the client (who is only responsible for the first instance). Also, the same would be said for `MoveManager` and responsibility of maintaining that.

**Update: Here's my `MoveManager` if it matters**

```
class MoveManager
{
    private:

        std::vector<Move*> _moves;

    public:

        void PushMove(Move& move)
        {
            _moves.push_back(&move);
        }


        void PopMove()
        {
            _moves.pop_back();
        }

        // Select a move by index.
        Move* SelectMove(int i)
        {
            return _moves[i];
        }

        // Get the number of moves.
        int GetMoveCount()
        {
            return (int)_moves.size();
        }
};
```

**Clarification: All I need is one collection of `Move` objects per thread. They are re-used every iteration, where `Perform` is called on different objects each time.**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem efficiently in a thread-safe manner?

Thanks!

Comment: "I cannot afford to instantiate a new Move object every iteration." Why? I'm not trying to doubt your judgement but with the code you put here I don't really see the difference between passing the `Object` to `perform()` and passing it to the constructor; they'd be doing the exact same amount of work, it seems.

Comment: Apart from allocating and deallocating the move object every iteration? As opposed to allocating the move object once and re-using it?

Comment: If you really want to use an abstract class like that (not saying it's wrong but there are often better options) then consider using a pool allocator like Boost.Pool. It operates on a block of memory and provides very fast allocation and deallocation for a single object type.

Comment: You could also use the same object pool concept on your suggested `State` objects. If your `State` objects would be trivially destructible, and you would only need to deallocate them all at once, you could even use a stack allocator for them. Very high performance -- cleanup of everything allocated is a simple pointer reset from the eyes of the allocator -- but the catch is that your objects being allocated from it must be trivially destructible. Unless you do extra bookkeeping, that is.

Comment: Can you mention one of the better options? Unfortunately I cannot have any external dependencies such as Boost.

Also, can you clarify what you mentioned about the `State` object. They should be trivial objects, basic structs with a few doubles, ints and strings. What would you suggest as a "stack allocator"? Do you just mean that the allocation and destruction on the stack normally would be an insignificant time penalty?

Comment: One of the "better options" would generally be automatic variables (i.e. "on the stack") but I understand that sometimes that is not viable; I can't see your entire architecture so I can't really say one way or the other for you. What I meant by "stack allocator" (I may have used the wrong term) is this: you have the allocator managing some block of memory, and it can hand allocate pieces of it in arbitrary sizes (like `new`) by keeping a pointer to the next free location and increment it by the size of an allocated chunk and return that original pointer when requested. (continued...)

Comment: Then when you're done with it, it'll just reset the pointer back to the beginning of it's managed block(s). The only prerequisite is that the objects you are constructing on those allocated chunks must have [trivial destructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor) so that not calling their destructors when throwing away their storage doesn't invoke undefined behavior. I don't know your entire program so I can't say this will help. It's useful when you need to allocate lots of stuff but can trash them all at once when you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the notion of a thread ID. Also, why not preconstruct the identifier strings and pass pointers to them?

```
class ConcreteMove : public Move
{
  std::string *_ns;
  std::vector<std::string *> _prev;
  std::vector<Object *> _obj;

  ConcreteMove(unsigned numthreads, std::string *newstring)
    : _ns(newstring),
      _prev(numthreads),
      _obj(numthreads)
  {
  }

  virtual void Perform(unsigned threadid, Object &obj) override
  {
    _obj[threadid] = &obj;
    _prev[threadid] = obj.GetIdentifier();
    obj.SetIdentifier(_ns);
  }

  virtual void Undo(unsigned threadid)
  {
    _obj[threadid]->SetIdentifier(_prev[threadid]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Oh interesting. That never crossed my mind for some reason. I think this may actually be what I'm looking for. One question though: how would I ensure having continuous threadIDs in each thread so I can supply them to the `Perform` move (so thread 1 is 0, thread 2 is 1, etc...)? Should the move manager be responsible for handing those out?

Comment: Yes, these would have to be explicitly assigned when the threads are created. If you somehow determine the parallel capabilities of your hardware platform at runtime (e.g. with `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`), you typically run a loop to create the right number of threads.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is actually an elegant solution to my problem that won't take too much reworking.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. While it is a working solution that require very little change, I'm not sure if the resulting solution is optimal in terms of performance and memory usage. If you reveal a little more information (number of objects intended, different move types, the larger goal generally) about why these constraints are so tight, I'm sure someone will be able to give an even better answer.

Comment: Also, you seem happy to add two member vectors to each Move object. Is it so clear that this is leaner than just creating a new collection of move objects for each thread, hence eliminating the need for thread safe Move objects. It's not clear to me.

Comment: These moves are used as a part of a simulation as described above. There are only a handful of moves in a simulation. However, they are called upon to perform the move billions of times. The reason I am hesitant to copy the objects is because then the original objects, initialized by the client, have a separate lifetime than the copies I have made. I don't think it is good practice to have the move manager be responsible for the copies but not the originals. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Are you sure vector makes sense? Wouldn't some kind of map make sense so its not as sparse?

Comment: I guess it's a performance/memory tradeoff as usual, and it's a little dependent on the intended number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with stated requirements. Specifically,

1. Use the command pattern. "the command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time." Thus you're storing data.
2. You "can't afford" to allocate memory.
3. You have "billions" of iterations, which means some large static allocation won't suffice.

You want to store data without any place to store it. Thus there is no answer. However, if you're willing to change your requirements, there are undoubtedly many ways to solve your problem (whatever it may be -- I couldn't tell from the description.)

I also can't estimate how many Move objects you need at once. If that number is reasonably low then a specialized allocation scheme might solve part of your problem. Likewise, if most of the Move objects are duplicates, a different specialized allocation scheme might help.

In general what you're asking can't be solved, but relax the requirements and it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify - I only need one Move object per thread (rather, one collection of move objects). I re-use them each iteration (I've edited the question to make this clear). To avoid the need to create and destroy move objects each iteration, I came up with the scheme I've shown above, where I pass in the object to be "moved" and store a pointer to it. The consequence of this is that I can no longer *reuse* a move object across multiple threads - I am looking for a suggestion on an alternative design. If it's not the command pattern then it's not. But as of now I'm stuck.

Comment: If you only need a collection of Move objects per thread, what's keeping you from making a copy of each Move object for each thread?

Answer (score 1):

Your Move Manager should not contain a vector of pointers, it should be a vector of Move objects

```
std::vector<Move> _moves;
```

It seems you will have one Move Manager per thread, so no issue of multi-threading problems, set the vector capacity at max, and then apply perform and other actions on the move in the vector
No new allocation, and you will be reusing the move objects

Comment: But how will the Move Manager know how to initialize the Move objects? Each move object has a unique constructor specified by the client. They only share the common Move interface.

Comment: Change from constuctor to reinitializing, if you have a group of move children, you may have to use a union.  The idea is not to do memory allocation, so you reuse the queue, you lose some flexibility by optimizing the exact use case.  Change vector_move_ptrs [idx]=new x (a, b, c) to vector_moves [idx].reset (a, b, c), placement new can work if you need polymorphism